# argparse: How to allow multiple names for single argument?

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to use more than one name to refer to a single argument in argparse?
Specifically, I want to allow user to specify an argument by either underscore and hyphen (dash)?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input-file')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

For example, I want both of the following options to work for the argument `args.input_file`:

```
python main.py --input-file /tmp/file
python main.py --input_file /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply listing more options in `.add_argument()`:

```
arg_parser.add_argument('--input-file', '--input_file')
```

should do the trick.

Note that using a minus `-` character in your argument is the [preferred GNU syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html).

---

Note that the names can be totally unrelated, e.g.:

```
arg_parser.add_argument('-bar', '--foo', '--input-file', '--input_file')
```

In this case, the first value starting with `--` (normalized) is used in the arguments namespace:

```
args = arg_parser.parse_args()
print(args)
# Namespace(foo=...)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the name of the element in the code then? is it the first, last, or all? (So `args.input-file` or `args.input_file`)

Comment: @gr4nt3d It is going to be the first valid one, normalized. See edits.